# how to load address of a label into register in powerpc

Tags: inline-assembly, powerpc

In a piece of inline assembly code, what is the best way to load the address of a label into a register?

I can do this easily in x86 or ARM. E.g.

```
 lea my_label, %rax
 ...
 my_label:
 ...
```

In PPC, should I use `$PC` and relative address to compute the address of the label? How to do that?

Thanks

Comment: Try moving `.` into a register.

Comment: Thanks, Alexey. Can you elaborate? what does '.' mean?

Comment: [The Special Dot Symbol](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Dot.html).

Comment: On x86-64, `lea my_label, %rax` uses a 32-bit absolute address.  You almost never want that for LEA, use `lea my_label(%rip), %rax` for position-independent RIP-relative or if you can take advantage of 32-bit absolute addressing for static addresses, use  `mov my_label, %eax`.  (Note the EAX destination to zero-extend into RAX).

Comment: If this is *inline* assembly, can't you just ask the compiler to give you the address in a register as an input?  Like `extern char my_label[];`  then `asm("..." : outputs : [label_addr] "r" (my_label) : clobbers);`

Comment: @Peter Cordes, 'my_label' is a label declared inside the inline assembly. So I think  put it in the input operands of inline assembly wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

OK, it's probably more complex than I thought. This might work:

```
void* f(void)
{
  void* var_reg;
  asm volatile(
      "lis %[var_reg], my_label@ha\n"
      "la %[var_reg], my_label@l(%[var_reg])\n"
      "my_label:\n"
      : [var_reg]"=&r"(var_reg)
  );
  return var_reg;
}
```